# Blink script gives me "name error 'BCM' is not defined"

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 2 and I am trying to run a simple a simple Blink program but getting this error:

> name error 'BCM' is not defined

This is my script

```python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO,BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

led = 7

while True:
    GPIO.output(led,1)
    time.sleep(2)
    GPIO.output(led,0)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please be so kind to share your program/script you're running. (Note that you can always edit your own question to include that information, no need to go through comments.)

Comment: sorry i paste code in comment

Comment: i am new here !!!

Comment: Not a problem, I edited the question for you. You are new to the site, we're here to help you along. Take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's GPIO.BCM you want. Dot rather than comma.

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
```